# Is it possible to search for questions that have a specific number of tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, search-box

**Is there a way to search for questions by the quantity of tags that are attached?**

I know that there are [Advanced Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) where you can refine your search, and I know that there is the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) which might offer some more flexibility, but I have not found any documentation on how to accomplish this task based on my research.

Consider the following situation: if a new user would like to achieve the [Organizer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5/organizer), for performing their first retag, then browsing questions that already have 5 tags is not entirely efficient.

It would be nice to be able to filter questions by minimum, maximum, or exact number of tags.

For example, it would be helpful to have a Range Operator called `tags:` where you could filter questions as such:

```
title:"javascript" "javascript" -[javascript] tags:4    is:question closed:no duplicate:no
title:"javascript" "javascript" -[javascript] tags:1..  is:question closed:no duplicate:no
title:"javascript" "javascript" -[javascript] tags:..2  is:question closed:no duplicate:no
title:"javascript" "javascript" -[javascript] tags:3..5 is:question closed:no duplicate:no
```

There are currently three other Range Operators than behave the same way: `score:`, `views:`, and `answers:`.

If there is not an intuitive or easy way to accomplish this task, I would like to request this feature.

Comment: I know you're not asking for a Data Explorer query (which is why I'm not posting this as an answer), but [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/870916/questions-with-a-certain-number-of-tags) searches for questions with a specific number of tags.

Comment: Why would browsing questions with 5 tags be inefficient? You're assuming that tags are only ever going to be added, but that is probably the situation that happens least often. Almost all re-tags I do are removing wrong tags (so many people tagging [tag:sql-server] and [tag:mysql], it's exhausting)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a need for this outside of facilitating lazy edits.  But you can use the API or a userscript to filter to the desired number of tags automatically (with a little work).